# Unbind HasAndBelongsToMany in CakePHP 2 doesn't unbind the model

Tags: php, cakephp-2.8

How to unbind `HasAndBelongsToMany` relationship in CakePHP 2.8? I have this model that is connected to Task model (N:M relationship).

```
class Date extends AppModel
{

    public $name = 'Date';
    public $displayField = 'rdate';
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Task' => array('className' => 'Task'));

    public function getCurrentDate()
    {
        return $this->find('first',
            array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Date.rdate' => date('Y-m-d')
                )
            )
        );
    }

}
```

I would like to unbind in `getCurrentDate()` function this relationship, but `$this->recursive = -1;` in this function nor in `find()` doesn't work. I need only one record from `Date` model but find returns all Tasks in relationship with this model.

**Edit#1:** Even unbinding model on the fly doesn't work:

```
$this->unbindModel(
    array('hasAndBelongsToMany' => array('Task'))
);
```

still returns associated model data.

Answer (score 0):

You can unbind models on the fly using `unbindModel()`.  Check out these docs for the specifics.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#creating-and-destroying-associations-on-the-fly

Comment: What about adding `$this->Behaviors->unload('Containable');`

Comment: No, it has no effect.